# Linear transformation (plz explain in details)

Tags: linear-transformations

For a positive integer $n$, let $P_n$ denote the vector space of polynomials in one variable $x$ with real coefficients and with degree $\le n$. Consider the map $T:P_2\to P_4$ defined by $T(p(x))=p(x^2)$. Then

1. $T$ is a linear transformation of dimension 5
2. $T$ is linear of dimension 3
3. $T$ is linear of dimension 2
4. $T$ is not a linear transformation.

Comment: I don't see any question marks, so I don't know what you're trying to ask. My guess though is that you're asking us to do your homework, and posing the request poorly.

Comment: What are you having difficulties with? Have you tried answering the question? You need try doing the question and then ask a more specific question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For any scalars $\alpha,\beta$ and $p_1,p_2\in P_2$, $$T(\alpha p_1(x)+\beta p_2(x))=T((\alpha p_1+\beta p_2)(x))=(\alpha p_1+\beta p_2)(x^2)\\=\alpha p_1(x^2)+\beta p_2(x^2)=\alpha T(p_1(x))+\beta T(p_2(x))$$
Hence $T$ is  linear transformation.
Also any $p\in P_2$ is of the form $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. So $T(p(x))=ax^4+bx^2+c$. Hence $T(P_2)$ can be spanned by the basis $\{1,x^2,x^4\}$. So $$\dim(T)=3$$

Comment: Have i done this wrong? Why is it downvoted?

Comment: That is not what is given in the question, it says $T(p(x))=p(x^2)$, and NOT $T(p(x))=(p(x))^2$

Comment: No. U have done good.. Thank u a lot